# Free RTOS for windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, rtos

Is there any free alternative to [TenAsys Intime RTOS](http://www.tenasys.com/products/intime.php), that comes fully integrated with Visual Studio 2010? Or if they aren't, which of the RTOS tools would you recommend me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of similar commercial products, but I do not believe that there is a free solution.

A do-it-your-self solution is possible using virtualisation:  You could for example use the free VirtualBox, VMWare Server, or Virtual PC, and run a free or open source RTOS such as eCOS in the VM.  Communication between the VM and the host can be implemented using TCP/IP over a virtual network.  This has the advantage that your solution can easly be redeployed as distributed system by using two real machines rather than a VM.

I would not get too hung-up on Visual Studio integartion if you want a free solution.  You can use Visual Studio, or even the free VC++ Express IDE to develop code for the RTOS target my using a "makefile project" and add your own build commands, and you get the same "Intellisense" code navigation (if you add the header paths to the configuration).  You will not of course get the full project management and dependency generation, you will need to provide that yourself using a makefile or similar tool, and you cannot use the VC++ debugger; you'll have to use an external tool such as GDB over a TCP/IP connection to the virtual target.

Comment: I'm not sure that the RTOS-inside-VM solution could work reliably. If the actual OS hosting the VM engine, is not a hard-real-time one, the whole system, including the VM-emulated environment is not real-time, so it will suffer the same non-determinism of the host OS. Instead, the opposite has a chance to work: a true RTOS may guest a non-RTOS inside a VM. The problem is that there are few VM for RTOS. Linux with RT extension (e.g. RTAI, or the low-latency patch) + VMware (or similar) may do the job.